# xsd schema mandatory elements by attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

please consider the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asset>
  <object name="pippo" logical="pippo"></object>
  <object name="pluto" logical="pluto"></object>
  <object name="paperino" logical="paperino"></object>
  <object name="ziopaperone" logical="paperino"></object>
  <object name="topolino" logical="paperino"></object>
</asset>
```

I need to write a schema with the following constraints:

1. objects with name "pippo" and "pluto" must exist and appear only once
2. objects with other names may exist or not
3. the attribute "name" and "logical" must be equal ( but this is not so mandatory )

I have been able to specify the point number 1, by specifying the simpleType for the name as being a subset of xs:ID with restriction on the value, but I can't figure out how to combine point 1 with point 2.

Can you help me? Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is not directly possible with XSD, because it will require you to create three types (one for "pippo", one for "pluto" and one for the rest), but with the same element name. And any element with the same path must, by definition, have the same type. If you would try what you are suggesting, you would receive the following error:

> E [Xerces] cos-element-consistent: Error for type 'objectType'. Multiple elements with name 'object', with different types, appear in the model group.

Since all your rules have as base rule that "anything goes", it is not possible with XSD 1.0 alone to fix this, because it would create ambiguous elements: a processor will not be able to know whether the first `object` in your example above is of the "objects with other names" type, or of the "only pippo/pluto" type. Such ambiguities are not allowed (and would cause problems if someone were to try to map the model to a POCO or POJO).

There is, however, a workaround. If you can use XSD 1.1, you can use assertions. For instance, the following works (which includes your rule #3, but enforced (as with the last part of that sentence in your Q. it becomes no rule at all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="urn:test" 
    targetNamespace="urn:test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="asset" type="objectType">        
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="objectType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="object" type="objectOtherType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="object[1]/@name = 'pippo'" xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"/>
        <xs:assert test="object[2]/@name = 'pluto'" xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"/>
        <xs:assert test="every $o in object satisfies $o/@logical = $o/@name" xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="objectOtherType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="otherNames" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="logical" type="otherNames" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="otherNames">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

If XSD 1.1 is not possible in your case, you should reconsider your object model (which may be a good idea in the first place), for instance, by using unique names for the elements that have unique properties, so that you can enforce the model.

As another alternative, consider using RelaxNG or Schematron as a schema language, both allow this kind of constraints. You can also combine Schematron (which works excellent and much like the assertions in XSD 1.1) with your existing XSD schema.